# Vertical align button in the middle of the column- bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and trying to vertically align the button in the column.

Note : I cant use flex and also I can't define height as per standards.

If I use margins it won't work in tablet and mobile devices.

So below is my code :

```css
.col-xs-2, .col-xs-6 {
   display: inline-block;
}
.col-xs-2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
     
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
             <h4>Some really large label that will wrap to multiple lines in small screens</h4>

        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
             <h4>Some really large label that will wrap to multiple lines in small screens</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button class="btn" style="color: #660066;"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" data-ng-click="onClickBack()"></i>

            </button>
        </div><!-- 
     -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Link:](http://jsfiddle.net/g0yzhgc2/)

So my question is how can I make the **arrow button** align to the middle of the row.
I have tried : `display:table-cell` and `display: inline-block;`
nothing seems to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm afraid it's a little bit difficult to understand what you want.  Can you please upload an image showing what you want?

Comment: arrow button button in the middle of the row.

Comment: Which row, on the same line as the second text element, on the next line?  Also, if you mean in the middle 'left-right,' that is 'horizontal,' not 'vertical.'  I think maybe you are after horizontal centering.

Comment: I am looking for vetical alignment only.

Comment: @user2936008
Can't you just shift the arrow div before the col-xs-6 div, that way it will occupy the middle position in the row ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[working JS Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/y5457tn9/)

CSS changes :

```
.col-xs-2, .col-xs-6 {
   display: inline-block;
}
.vcenter {
     float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from the different cases of this problem and the source code mentioned on this link [here](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height).

---

Check my working fiddle with support for different media as well: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/e6w63g7o/)

---

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-height">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-height">
        <div class="inside">
          <div class="content">
            <h4>Some really large label that will wrap to multiple lines in small screens</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-height col-middle">
        <div class="inside">
          <div class="content">
            <h4>Some really large label that will wrap to multiple lines in small screens</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-height col-middle">
        <div class="inside">
          <div class="content">
            <button class="btn" style="color: #660066;"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" data-ng-click="onClickBack()"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS :**

```
  .inside {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.content {
  padding: 12px 3px;
}
.row-height {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.col-height {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.col-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.col-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .row-xs-height {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xs-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .col-xs-top {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .col-xs-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .col-xs-bottom {
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-sm-height {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-top {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .col-sm-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .col-sm-bottom {
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row-md-height {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-top {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .col-md-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .col-md-bottom {
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row-lg-height {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-top {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .col-lg-middle {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .col-lg-bottom {
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
}
body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
  color: #95c500;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  border: none;
  background: #ffffff;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  display: table;
}
body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Does it work according to your requirements, and is your question answered?

Comment: yes it works. Please check my answer too just now figured it .

Comment: @user2936008 : you mentioned earlier that you didnt want to use margins ? but your answer has a margins attribute as well ?

Comment: yes. I didnt want to use top and bottom margin .which would make it static and wouldnt work in different views.